# ps command in sh script not include the top command

Tags: bash

I have written a script to check process is running or not,it work fine but while testing it, i have found that it not include top command count running in other terminal

check-process.sh

```
 #!/bin/sh 
 OK=1
 CRITICAL=0
 PROCESS_NUM=$( ps -ef | grep $1 | grep -v "grep "|grep -v "sh"|wc -l )
 #echo $PROCESS_NUM

 if [ $PROCESS_NUM = $OK ]
 then
  echo "OK"
 elif [ $PROCESS_NUM = $CRITICAL ]
 then
  echo "CRITICAL"
 elif [ $PROCESS_NUM > $OK ]
 then
  echo "MULTIPLE process are runing"
 else
  echo "error"
 fi
```

And i run **top command in two terminals** and run this script as follow:

> **./check-process.sh top**

and out put is **0 CRITICAL** , but when i run normal command `ps -ef |grep -v "grep "| wc -l` it gives two counts.

Comment: Why do you `grep` for the pattern `"sh"`?

Comment: Is your username "manish" or "manishj" or something like that? Because if it is that or anything else that contains "sh", the `grep -v "sh"` is going to remove all of your processes from the list.

Comment: Hmm. Your question is tagged **[tag:bash]**, but your script uses `#!/bin/sh`. Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

That mess of `grep`s just has to go.

One "trick" for finding processes by name without finding your grep is to use a regular expression. That is, after all, what the Global Regular Expression Print command is for.  You can use parameter expansion to construct a safe regular expression based on your input string, perhaps like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "I'd love me an option." >&2
  exit 1
fi

OK=1
CRITICAL=0

x="${1#?}"                 # make a temporary string missing the 1st chararcter,
re="[${1%$x}]$x"           # then place the 1st character within square brackets.

PROC_COUNT=$( ps -ef | grep -w -c "$re" )       # yay, just one pipe.

if [ "$PROC_COUNT" -eq "$OK" ]; then
  echo "OK"
elif [ "$PROC_COUNT" -eq "$CRITICAL" ]; then
  echo "CRITICAL"
elif [ "$PROC_COUNT" -gt "$OK" ]; then
  echo "MULTIPLE process are running"
else
  echo "error"
fi
```

There are a few notable changes here:

- I added something to fail with better explanation if no option is given.
- The pipeline, of course. And the lines that create `$re`.
- We're using `-gt` and `-eq` to test numeric values. `man test` for details.
- I renamed your count variable to be clearer. What is a "PROCESS_NUM" really? Sounds like a PID to me.
- All variables are quoted. I don't need to tell you why, you have the Google.

That said, you should also consider using `pgrep` instead of any sort of counting pipe, if it's available on your system. Try running `pgrep` and see what your OS tells you.